# What foods or substances can feed your muscles with energy without feeding the bad bacteria in your guts?

Tags: nutrition, muscle-gain, energy, carbohydrate

Many pathogenic bacteria (those promoting inflammation, insulin resistance etc) and fungi in the gut microbiome feed on sugar and starches (perhaps some good bacteria can feed on these too, I don't really know, the majority of the beneficial bacteria are supposed to feed on polysacharides like inulin etc. AFAIK). The question is what are some foods or supplements that one can consume instead of ordinary sugar/starch to feed the muscles with easily available energy when training to gain the muscle mass efficiently if they would like to avoid feeding the bacteria at the same time?